# Different HMAC results in C# and C++

Tags: sha1, hmacsha1

I have one solution in visual studio 2010. It has two projects, one is written in C# and the other is written in C++. They are completely independent of one another. I am having an issue trying to produce the same result from the two projects. The C++ project can have no .NET dependencies and the two projects must produce the same result using the SHA1 algorithm. I have my C++ code matching this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382379(v=vs.85).aspx. I would like to replicate the C++ code in the C# project and get the same result.

Currently, I am getting different results. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing "creating an HMAC of input data using SHA-1 as the hash function" - which is what the code you point to does, and "calculating the SHA-1 hash corresponding to input data", which might be what you want based on your title?

Comment: I need to accomplish the first suggestion. Create an HMAC of input data using SHA-1 as the hash function in C#.